# Is it possible to implement rate limiting with Geode Redis Adapter?

Tags: redis, geode, spring-cloud-gateway

I am trying to use Geode Redis Adapter as my server for Rate Limiting provided by Spring Cloud Gateway. If I use a real Redis Server, everything works perfectly, but with Geode Redis Adapter doesn't.
I am not too sure if this functionality is supported.

I tried to start a [Geode image] (https://hub.docker.com/r/apachegeode/geode/) exposing the default Redis port *6739*. Starting the container, I executed using *gfsh* the following commands:
`start server --name=redis --redis-port=6379 --J=-Dgemfireredis.regiontype=PARTITION_PERSISTENT`

When I try to access in my local machine by `redis-cli -h localhost -p 6379` I can get connected.

My implementation is simple:

application.yaml

```
      - id: rate-limitter
        predicates:
          - Path=${GUI_CONTEXT_PATH:/rate-limit}
          - Host=${APP_HOST:localhost:8080}
        filters:
          - name: RequestRateLimiter
            args:
              key-resolver: "#{@remoteAddrKeyResolve}"
              redis-rate-limiter:
                replenishRate: ${rate.limit.replenishRate:1}
                burstCapacity: ${rate.limit.burstCapacity:2}
        uri: ${APP_HOST:localhost:8080}
```

Application.java

```
  @Bean
  KeyResolver remoteAddrKeyResolve() {
    return exchange -> Mono.just(exchange.getSession().subscribe().toString());
  }
```

When my application is started and I try to access */rate-limit*, I expected to connect to redis and my page be displayed.

However, my Spring application keeps trying to access and can't `i.l.c.p.ReconnectionHandler: Reconnected to localhost:6379`. So, the page is not displayed and keep loading. **FIXED in Edit1 below**

**Problem** is I am using RedisRateLimiter and tried to simulate the access with a for loop. Checking the RedisRateLimiter.REMAINING_HEADER, the value is -1 always. Doesn't seems right, because I don't have this issue in Redis itself.
During the start of the application, I also receive these messages on connection to Geode Redis Adapter:
`Starting without optional epoll library`
`Starting without optional kqueue library`

Is anything missing in my Geode Redis Adapter or anything else in Spring?
Thank you

**Edit 1:** I was missing to start the locator and region, that's why I wasn't able to connect.
`start locator --name=locator`
`start server --name=redis --redis-port=6379 --J=-Dgemfireredis.regiontype=PARTITION_PERSISTENT`
`create region --name=redis-region --type=REPLICATE_PERSISTENT`

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if this would work since Spring Cloud Gateway executes a lua script to calculate the remaining RPS. Could be that this is not working with Geode.
Try to see if it can execute this script on `RedisRateLimiter`L225.

Comment: Tysewyn, I think you maybe be right. I am using RedisRateLimiter and tried to simulate the access with a for. Checking the RedisRateLimiter.REMAINING_HEADER, the value is -1.
Would it respond your suggestion?
I am updating the question.